# "We met when we were studying" vs. "when we had studied"

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect, progressive-aspect

Which one is correct?

> 1. We met when we **were studying** in North Korea.
> 2. We met when we **had studied** in North Korea.

Could you give me a detailed explanation please?

Comment: "We met when we had studied in North Korea" makes little, if any, sense. The first example is correct.

Comment: Why not ?  like  "  As soon as she CAME in I knew I HAD SEEN her before "   " past tense + P. P "  indicates that " P.P" occured first and then  " past tense " occured .  Likewise, We studied in North Korea  and then We met .

Comment: In that case, it should be *We met when (after?) we had **finished** studies in NK.*

Comment: @18yoPolyglot The sentence is like this: "As soon as she CAME in I KNEW I had seen her before". The coming in and the knowing are at the same time, the seeing is before both of them; that is why "came" and "knew" are past simple, and "had seen" - P.P. In the other sentences the meeting and the studying happened at the same time, there is no one action before the other.

Answer (score 2):

*We me when we were studying in North Korea* makes sense because the two events are linked. Why did you meet? Because you were both studying in the same country, and most likely in the same university. The time of the actual meeting is *when* you were in the process of studying.

In the example in your comment *As soon as she came in I knew I had seen her before* the events are linked. You knew you had seen her before because you saw her when she came in, and the time realising you had seen her before is *when* she cam in.

*We met when we had studied in North Korea* makes little sense on its own because having studied in North Korea has no logical link to a subsequent meeting, and the time of the meeting is not *when* you had studied in North Korea.

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with whether events are linked. It's about placing the event with respect to the point of time you are focussing on. _When I had had lunch, there was a knock on the door_, has no logical link between the events, but it places them temporally relative to each other, differently from _when I was having lunch there was a knock on the door_.

Comment: Your sentence makes sense only if the door being knocked on is your door, and the room behind it is the room you had lunch in, and the knock on the door occured in the same time frame. That is at least 3 logical links. If the lunch you are talking about was in 1996 and the knock was on a random door in 2014, the sentence makes no sense. If you are going to insist that no link is needed, only a temporal sequence, then you would have to accept sentences like "Maglev trains were developed when Hannibal had crossed the Alps" as unproblematic.

Comment: @ColinFine Agree with Roaring Fish. That's because the question in concern has *when* in it! It **must** denote some relation between those two occasions

Comment: +1 for the subtlety defined and especially for the last paragraph. I too think putting word *when* makes the second sentence ambiguous though grammatically passable.

Comment: OK, it's about how the events are linked; but the linking need only be a narrative one that the speaker is making for the purposes of this utterance, not necessarily any objective or causative connection.